# How to set trigger on specific folder and branch

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - main
 paths:
   include:
      - FPH.IaC/IAC/*
```

Hi, I want my yaml pipeline only triggered when files under a specific folder (FPH.IaC/IAC/) of main branch is changed.

However, with this yaml, the pipeline is triggered every time some file is changed under main branch. Is it branch and Path is actually an OR relationship or I did something wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit the pipeline definition to confirm that the [Override the YAML trigger from here setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#i-just-created-a-new-yaml-pipeline-with-cipr-triggers-but-the-pipeline-is-not-being-triggered) is not enabled, otherwise, it should work and if it doesn't provide any example.